# Query regarding spouse visa

Tags: schengen

I am from India and got married in India with an Estonian Woman who is older than me by 15 years. She is working in Finland and is holding resident permit too and our marriage also got registered in Finland. I have also applied for visa from Finnish Embassy in New Delhi.

Is it possible for us to appeal somewhere if my visa gets rejected? From the embassy staff's reaction I feel like they will reject my visa as we have submitted all the documents which has been mentioned.

Please if any one can give me information regarding this i will be really thankful.

Comment: Speculative at this point as we don't know why they would refuse your visa.